# Combine 2 records as one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine 2 records as one, I have seen some similar questions but these seem to be not a specific record in the DB

```
 SELECT Summary1 as a, Summary2 as b, Summary3 as c, DateUpdated as d
FROM  tbl_EC where id=1

SELECT Summary1 as e, Summary2 as f, Summary3 as g, DateUpdated as h
FROM  tbl_EC where id=2
```

Comment: I think you want to show data as `comma separated values` (i.e. [a,b, c, d, e, f, g, h] as one column. ), then try `STUFF` function.

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join:

```
SELECT t1.Summary1 as a, t1.Summary2 as b, t1.Summary3 as c, t1.DateUpdated as d,
       t2.Summary1 as e, t2.Summary2 as f, t2.Summary3 as g, t2.DateUpdated as h
FROM  tbl_EC t1
    JOIN tbl_EC t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
WHERE t1.ID = 1
```

Perhaps you want to switch to `FULL OUTER JOIN`, if any id may be missing?

```
SELECT t1.Summary1 as a, t1.Summary2 as b, t1.Summary3 as c, t1.DateUpdated as d,
       t2.Summary1 as e, t2.Summary2 as f, t2.Summary3 as g, t2.DateUpdated as h
FROM  tbl_EC t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_EC t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
                             and (t1.id % 2 = 1 or t2.id % 2 = 0)
```

Comment: Apologies, but I can return the records, however I would like them to be presented as one record i.e.  a, ,b, c, d, e, f, g, h

Comment: Ahh, I see. Do both the queries return exactly 1 row?

Comment: Yes only one row, if it exists in the DB

Comment: Use the FULL OUTER JOIN version if you want a result even if one of the rows is missing.

Comment: many thanks Jarlh, the first option works but only if the record exists, do I need to add the ID for t2 which should 2. I tried option 2 but I receive an error MOD is not recognised

Comment: Instead of MOD, you could try `(t1.id % 2 = 1 or t2.id % 2 = 0)`.